# Limit Resources actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :countries do
    resources :cities
end
```

But I only want:

```
new:    GET     /countries/:id/cities/new
create: POST    /countries/:id/cities
```

And not the 7 actions.

What can I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here you go:

```
resources :cities, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Reference [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 resources :cities, :only => [:new,:create]
```